# Can't Access CSV files using Pandas in Spyder

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, spyder

For some weird reason, Anaconda on my Mac got uninstalled and since I installed it again, I've not been able to access the files/datasets that I had accessed earlier.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: The code]

[image: Console Output]

**I'm able to access the same files in PyCharm IDE** but I've not been able to do so in Spyder. It'd be great if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to restart the whole machine. or do any updates

Comment: Restarting doesn't work